# Hibernate querying on a parent class creates ineffective union query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot and hibernate and I have following data structure.

```
@Entity
public class Template {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "template", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @BatchSize(size = 30)
  private Collection<TemplateContent> contents;
}

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class TemplateContent {

  @Id
  private String contentType;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "template_id", nullable = false)
  private Template template;
}

@Entity
public class SomeContent extends TemplateContent {

   private String someValue;
}

@Entity
public class SomeOtherContent extends TemplateContent {

   private String someOtherValue;
}

@Repository
public interface TemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<Template, Integer> {
  Page<Template> findByIdIn(Collection<Integer> ids, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I call findByIdIn method it generates the following query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   (SELECT content_type, 
               template_id, 
               some_value, 
               NULL AS some_other_value
        FROM   someContent
        UNION 
    SELECT content_type, 
               template_id, 
               some_other_value, 
               NULL AS some_value
        FROM   someOtherContent) contents0_ 
WHERE  contents0_.template_id IN ( ?, ?, ? )
```

which is ineffective, because MySQL can't use indexes over derived tables. Is there a way to generate a more effective query.

```
//this would be the desired query
SELECT ...
FROM   (SELECT content_type, 
               template_id, 
               some_value, 
               NULL AS some_other_value
        FROM   someContent
        WHERE template_id IN ( ?, ?, ? )
        UNION 
    SELECT content_type, 
               template_id, 
               some_other_value, 
               NULL AS some_value
        FROM   someOtherContent
        WHERE template_id IN ( ?, ?, ? )) contents_0_ ....
```

I tried also to use different inheritance strategies, but it seems like all of them have a similar drawback.

Comment: Have you tried the single table strategy ?

Comment: The actual contents have a totally different data structures, so I try not to save all of them on one table. Also, I have 8 different content types.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have best performance in polymorphic query the best approach is to use `strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`, probably you will pay performance with empty columns, but it depends which aspect is more important for you, also because `strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED` has same problems of `TABLE_PER_CLASS`

Comment: The problem is that I have different content types, and each of them has a totally different data model. I wonder if there is a way to "hint" hibernate to generate a proper query.

Comment: It is already a proper query. It's not proper the polymorphism you have, as you said, with totally different model data

Comment: Can you please explain more, what is wrong with data model. I have around 8 content types and each of them has 5-6 fields which are specific to it's type, and 4 other fields which are shared with other content types. Creating a table with 50 columns doesn't make sense on one point, and content types can be enhanced with the period of time.

Comment: One one side you have 50 column on the other you have a join between 8 tables. What makes sense or not is only based on your needs and scenario.